# Liquibase loadData changeset ignores context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase

I have a jhipster project, with Java, Spring and Liquibase as always. I want to load mock users on "dev" mode only, but when deploying to Heroku using the "prod" profile, they are ALSO loaded. It's like the context is ignored completely by liquibase. What am I doing wrong here?

The application-prod.yml file has a liquibase context set to "prod"

```
spring:
    liquibase:
        contexts: prod
```

and the application-dev.yml is setting liquibase context to "dev":

```
spring:
    liquibase:
        contexts: dev
```

I have some mock user data that I want to load only on dev (when running on localhost), and the liquibase changeset looks like this:

```
<changeSet author="me" id="mock-data-1" context="dev" >

        <loadData encoding="UTF-8"
                  file="config/liquibase/mock_users.csv"
                  separator=";"
                  tableName="jhi_user">
            <column name="activated" type="boolean"/>
            <column name="created_date" type="timestamp"/>
        </loadData>

        ...

</changeSet>
```

All other changesets have no context applied.

(Probably not relevant but) my mock_users.csv looks like this:

```
id;login;password_hash;first_name;last_name;email;image_url;activated;lang_key;created_by;last_modified_by;created_date;team_id
5;user1;$2a$10$VEjxo0jq2YG9Rbk2HmX9S.k1uZBGYUHdUcid3g/vfiEl7lwWgOH/K;;;user1@localhost.com;;true;sv;system;system;2019-12-03T09:21:06Z;1
```

Here is my Procfile for Heroku deployment:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.war --spring.profiles.active=prod,heroku --server.port=$PORT 
release: cp -R src/main/resources/config config && ./mvnw liquibase:update -Pheroku
```

When deploying to Heroku however the logs say thay no context is set at all:

```
Liquibase settings:
...
2019-12-03T13:17:08.821255+00:00 app[release.7646]: [INFO]     context(s): null
...
```

And the entire changeLog is executed, I can see that in the Heroku logs too.

How do I make sure the liquibase contexts from my application-prod.yml file are used correctly?

**EDIT*** I can make heroku run liquibase with prod context by editing the pom file, under the "heroku" profile, "liquibase maven plugin" setting the "contexts" tag:

```
<profile>
            <id>heroku</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration combine.self="override">
                            <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                            <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                            <driver></driver>
                            <url>${env.JDBC_DATABASE_URL}</url>
                            <defaultSchemaName></defaultSchemaName>
                            <username>${env.JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}</username>
                            <password>${env.JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}</password>
                            <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:se.axesslab.respekttrappan.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <contexts>prod</contexts>
                            <logging>debug</logging>
                            <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

But should this really be required? Then what's the point of having the application-*.yml files hold different liquibase contexts?

Comment: why don't you use `application.yml` instead of `application-prod.yml`?

Comment: Or you try setting, `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` as JVM argument

Comment: @MohamedSaligh because I want different settings for dev, prod and test, and I only use application.yml for common settings.

Comment: @MohamedSaligh I do that, see my post. "--spring.profiles.active=prod,heroku"

Comment: it is recommended to have prod configs with `application.yml` remaining will be with different profiles like `'dev','test','qa'`. Also noticed that JVM argument that you pass `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.war --spring.profiles.active=prod,heroku`, shouldn't be having something like `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` ? I am not sure how heroku thing works, but, JVM argument works same across platform. double check that may solve the issue.

Comment: @MohamedSaligh I have not written any of this setup that you mention, it's a generated project using jhipster, see https://www.jhipster.tech/. The spring profiles are set correctly so no issues there. It's just the liquibase context that isn't set even though it's in the spring application-*.yml file

Comment: Could it be a compilation issue? Do you compile with the correct profile? (i.e. `./mvnw clean` followed by `./mvnw -Pprod package`)

Comment: Hi @JavaDevSweden , how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The execution of Liquibase is triggered from within the Maven plugin, `./mvnw liquibase:update -Pheroku`. The maven plugin doesn't know about the Liquibase context you set in Spring's property file.

Like you figured out yourself, you have to either set the context in the pom.xml or let Spring execute Liquibase.

Comment: Is this still valid? Do you have any idea on how to set this in the POM?

Comment: @desoss see the last "Edit" part of my question.